# My Forward smart contract sending funds to 0x000000000000

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging

This is my coding below.  When funds are sent to this contract they are supposed to be forwarded to the creator of the smart contract, however it is not working. All funds are being sent to 0x000000000000000000 ethereum address.

contract address is https://etherscan.io/address/0x6f3c294288c62ff70d6274c73741e16d3113f37d

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Forward {

  address public destinationAddress;
  event LogForwarded(address indexed sender, uint amount);
  event LogFlushed(address indexed sender, uint amount);

  function constuctor() public {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  function() payable public {
    emit LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value);
    destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function flush() public {
    emit LogFlushed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    destinationAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor was never invoked. The constructor should be written without the keyword `function`. Moreover, spelling of constructor is also wrong.

The correct smart contract would be

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Forward {

  address public destinationAddress;
  event LogForwarded(address indexed sender, uint amount);
  event LogFlushed(address indexed sender, uint amount);

  constructor() public {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  function() payable public {
    emit LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value);
    destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function flush() public {
    emit LogFlushed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    destinationAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

**Update:**

And even this might fail to fulfill your purpose. Because you have written `flush` function, using which I assume you want the contract to store balance and later flush it to destination. But in the fallback function, you are instantly giving away the collected balance to `destinationAddress`. So contract will never store balance. If this is the case, you may want your fallback to look like this:

```
  function() payable public {
    emit LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value);
    // destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }
```

Or I may be wrong in assuming the use case you want.

Note: Most developers like to do testing on test networks. Just in case if you didn't know about them.