# How to automatically forward Ether that I receive on my one wallet to another?

Tags: solidity, wallets, smart-contract-wallets

Very basic understanding of Eth.
I have more than one wallets, addresses are given to different people to pay to.
I want to forward all incoming eth from those wallets to my master wallet.
How can I do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Ethereum protocol does not offer this functionality by default. You have to use a third-party service. I recommend [Gelato Ops](https://app.gelato.network/).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I do not understand https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time
checking Gelato Ops

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46505/87205 seems to be relevant, but not able to run this.

Comment: The idea is that you can't achieve this with Solidity alone. You have to rely on an off-chain solution. Check out Gelato.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a single individual with no programming skills, the best way to do this is to do it by hand.

If you are a professional building a service, [here is a description of payment forwarders that companies like Coinbase use](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84071/620).